# Problem with camera

Tags: android

I have one activity in which i have opened device camera and taking pictures after 1 min each.This is working without any problem.Now my camera is always on.When i press either home screen key or call key,my camera activity is going to background.When i again clicking on my application,ideally my camera activity should come to foreground and camera should be opened.

But this is not happening.When i am clicking on my application icon,my application is crashing.

Is anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thanks and Regards.

Rohan Wagh

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to look at LogCat and examine the stack trace associated with your crash, to learn where and why it is occurring.

Comment: Its difficult to diagnose without code or a debug dump, but one suggestion I have is to make sure that your camera app is releasing the camera resource properly when it loses focus. 
If you're not using Camera.stopPreview() and Camera.release() when your activity gets destroyed then the camera gets locked up and you have to reset the device to access it again.
Please provide us with some more detail and someone should be able to give you a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't release the camera when your application paused (went into the background), and when you re-activated your app (brought it to the foreground), your main activity probably called Camera.get() again. However, since your application already had possession of the camera from the earlier session, the system threw an exception and your application blew up.

In general, your application should always release the Camera object when your activity pauses (onPause()).

However, it sounds like you have it running in the background all the time, snapping pictures. In which case, your code needs to check to see if you already have the camera and  *do not* call Camera.get() again if that's the case.

Check out these topics on the Android developer site for some code examples:

- [Accessing the camera](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#access-camera)
- [Releasing the camera](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#release-camera)